# How to create a cognitive service to use Video API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm not able to create a cognitive service to use Video API.
Its currently not available from
[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXYNc.jpg).
Does anybody know the process of creating one.

Answer (score 0):

For a variety of reasons, the Azure Portal only lists APIs for which a paid tier exists.

You should be able to find all the information you need on the Microsoft Cognitive Service [Video API site](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/video-api), including a link to get a free tier API key.